# Trying to get a list of Teams a user has ownership

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Trying to get a list of Teams a specific user has ownership with Graph api.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

This command will provide a list of teams but you need to get the group id first:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/owners

I tried the following but I couldn't get the correct results.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$expand=owners($filter=userprinciplename eq '<>'&$select=id,displayname,userprinciplename)&$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')

Answer (score 3):

You can use ownedObjects to get the list of directory objects that are owned by the user. This includes Unified Groups in the groupTypes and output the resourceProvisioningOptions here too.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ownedObjects
```

more documentation on that here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-ownedobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs .

Unfortunately it is not supported to use $filter like this. So you'll have to do on your side. So  this won't work

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ownedObjects?$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')
```

Comment: Thank you... Well at least it gets me closer. I replace "me" with "<<UPN>>" which worked..  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<<UsersUPN>>/ownedObjects?$select=id,displayName,resourceProvisioningOptions   Hopefully "$filter" can be used in the near future.

Comment: @raquelcont i'd appreciate it if you marked this as the answer if it did help.

Answer (score -1):

Your query was incorrect. Please try the below updated query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$expand=owners($filter=userprinciplename eq 'add your mail id here')&select=id,displayname&$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')
```

Comment: I changed the attribute "userprincipalname" was incorrect. I have correct that but it still does not filter the user  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$expand=owners($filter=userPrincipalName eq  '<<UPN>>')&$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')&$select=userPrincipalName,id,displayname

Comment: The way this command is structured it should query every Team and look for owner with the upn specified. Unfortunately the results provided a list of Teams where match is on upn but that upn is not an owner.  8-(